# Multiple sources and condition

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying my best to figure out how AutoMapper works when mapping multiple sources to one destination and the sources have to be compared with each other.

### Source

```cs
public class ProductSource
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public List<AttributeValue> AttributeValues { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<AttributeKey> AttributeKeys { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeKey
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeValue
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public AttributeKey AttributeKey { get; set; }
}
```

Example output of the source in Json:

```json
"Product": {
    "Name": "Nikon D70s",
    "Category": {
        "Name": "Camera",
        "AttributeKeys": {
            { "Id": 1001, "Name": "Resolution" },
            { "Id": 1002, "Name": "Size" },
            { "Id": 1003, "Name": "Color" }

        }
    },
    "AttributeValues" {
        { "id": 10001, "Value": "6 megapixel", "AttributeKey": 1001 },
        { "id": 10002, "Value": "Black", "AttributeKey": 1003 }
    }
}
```

### Destination

```cs
public class ProductDestination
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Example of the output I wish for, in Json:

```json
"Product": {
    "Name": "Nikon D70s",
    "CategoryName": "Camera",
    "Attributes": {
        { "Name": "Resolution ", "Value": "6 megapixel" },
        { "Name": "Size", "Value": "" },
        { "Name": "Color", "Value": "Blue" }
    }
}
```

### I wish it was this easy

I was hoping it should be this easy to make the "automagic" mapping happen.

```cs
CreateMap<ProductSource, ProductDestination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.CategoryName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Category.Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.Attributes, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Category.AttributeKeyCategory.AttributeKeys));

CreateMap<AttributeKeys, Attribute>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name));

CreateMap<AttributeValue, Attribute>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Value, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Value));
```

How can I take two sources, compare them with each other and merge them into one destination?

Edit: When I mapp the AttributKey to Attribute, I need to go back to the grand-grand-parents other child (AttributeValue) and loop through all AttributeValues and if there is an instance with AttributeKeyId value that match the Id of my AttributeKey and then mapp this value to my Attribute...

Comment: Is `AttributeValue.AttributeKey` of type `AttributeKey` or `int`?

Comment: Its an `AttributeKey` type. Im using Entity FrameWork and there is also an `AttributeKeyId` prop that is an `int`

Comment: Haven't worked with EF, but if you already have `AttributeKey` inside `AttributeValue` then why not just add `.ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AttributeKey.Name));` to `AttributeValue` -> `Attribute` map?

Comment: It needs to be mapped from `Category.AttributeKeys` because not all `AttributeKey` has an  `AttributeValue`. And the application needs all `Keys`. See the "Size" in the Json output of an example.